# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "from" when doing db2 query to get all schemas

Tags: database, powershell, db2, schema

I am getting an error when trying to run a db2 select query to get all the schemas listed in a db2 database.

Here is the error:

> Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'from' .At line:5 char:1...

I don't see the issue here since this appears to be the correct format. My code is below:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=TESTDATABASE;HostName=DB2HOST.db2domain.net;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50002;Uid=adminID;Pwd=aPassWord;") 

$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$conn.Open(); 

set-item -path env:DB2CLP -value "**$$**"

Select  schemaname from syscat.schemata;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Select` is a bare-line command in PowerShell. `Select` is aliased to `Select-Object` and that's why you get the error.  You need to issue your `Select` to the database.

See examples like: 
[How To Execute MS Access Query with OLEDB.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905590/how-to-execute-ms-access-query-with-oledb-12)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855069.aspx
Note that this one incorrectly marks the PowerShell examples as C#.

Comment: @scot, please accept the answer if it solves your issue.