# How do I get to a specific table in an Access Database using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, com

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to open an Access Database and then open a specific table named "UserInfo" using PowerShell. At that point, I would modify the records within that table. As for now, I simply want to get to the table. I have this very basic code I saw somewhere else and modified a tad.  I have looked everywhere and can't find a solution to getting to this table.  Ultimately, I think that I am looking for a method to use in conjunction with DoCmd?

```
$filename = "Z:\Database2.accdb"
$accdb = New-Object -ComObject access.application
$accdb.Visible = $true
$accdb.OpenCurrentDatabase($filename)
$accdb.DoCmd
```

Comment: Have you consulted [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model)?

Comment: Honestly, what you want to do is this: 1) Write the code in VBA where you will have context sensitive help and online help 2) Once you figure it out in VBA, translate it to PowerShell

Comment: In case you want to edit records with sql, here's a related question-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905590/how-to-execute-ms-access-query-with-oledb-12

Comment: I have used VBScript to open a db and then pass control to user for interacting with db. Is that what you want to do? My script opens db and then code in db manages opening forms. Some features available to user depend on user's Windows ID and their permissions set in Users table. Script can also call Access macro or VBA procedure. Script can execute action SQL (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). Maybe you want `DoCmd.OpenTable`?

Comment: Thank you all for y'alls' comments. I will take a look at what each of you have said.